# Cannot find dependency from jitpack.io repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies, jitpack

i want to use dependency that needs a jitpack.io repository

Cannot find dependency when I try to sync , While available at jitpack.io

language kotlin

my gradle plugin version is 7.0.1

my gradle version is 7.0.2

Everything is updated

Dependency

```
implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.2.1'
```

Repository

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url 'https://jitpack.io/'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; 
they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

BuildOutput

```
Could not find com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.2.1.
```

I tested all versions of Independence

Comment: are you try using it with VPNs ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem was the Android Studio update on the Stable channel, which changed the structure of the gradle, and this problem will be solved by installing previous versions.